# MySQL Server Not Starting on Boot

Tags: mysql, rhel5

I have installed `MySQL` on a `RHEL 5 server` and I want to set it up so that the server starts on boot.

I've ran the `chkconfig --list mysqld` command and it's currently running on levels 3, 4 and 5.  However, when I reboot the server, no `mysqld` daemon is started.

I've also tried manually starting the server by executing `/usr/bin/mysqld_safe` and I get the following output:

```
Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
STOPPING server from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
100319 10:31:30  mysqld ended
```

I looked in `/var/log/mysqld.log` and I found the following:

```
100319 10:29:01  mysqld started
100319 10:29:02  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 29752204
100319 10:29:02 [ERROR] Can't start server : Bind on unix socket: Permission denied
100319 10:29:02 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock ?
100319 10:29:02 [ERROR] Aborting
```

UPDATE: I tried starting using the `mysql.server` script (from `/usr/share/mysql`) and it worked.So I went ahead and linked this script to the appropriate run levels (`rc0.d`, `rc3.d` and `rc5.d`).  However, it's still not starting on boot.

Answer (score 1):

Is this version of mysqld from the official repository or an rpm that you downloaded from mysql.com?

If mysql.server script works then you should be able to copy it to /etc/init.d and then symlink to it from /etc/rc3.d rc4.d and rc5.d.

Edit:
But you'll need to use chkconfig to turn mysqld off first before you do the symlinks.

Comment: Okay, I turned off chkconfig, created the sym links and then turned chkconfig back on.  When I rebooted, I checked the processes for mysql and it only showed this: 

> root  3306  2258  0 12:59 ?  00:00:00 /bin/sh /etc/rc5.d/S64mysqld start

Then when I ran ps again, it showed nothing (i.e. MySQL hadn't started).

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong but for some reason i get the feeling you're not running a mysql version provided by redhat and this is the cause of your problems.

When you create symlinks by hand you don't need to use chkconfig (that's one of the things chkconfig does).

ln -s /etc/init.d/mysql.server /etc/rc3.d/S65mysqld

Comment: I downloaded the RPM files from the MySQL site: MySQL-client-standard-5.0.27-0.rhel4.i386.rpm and MySQL-server-standard-5.0.27-0.rhel4.i386.rpm.  I needed the older version because the application I'm installing requires it.

Answer (score 1):

Remove /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock and then chkconfig mysqld on.  You can get a menu of services by running ntsysv.  Use man chkconfig and man ntsysv to learn more about how to use those programs.

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to install the `strace` package (it's in the standard YUM repository), then run:

```
strace /etc/init.d/mysqld start
```

You should be able to determine pretty quickly where the error lies.

On RHEL/CentOS, you generally want to use the init script for stopping and starting the mysqld daemon -- it does a lot more than simply start `/usr/bin/mysqld_safe&`.

Comment: I tried running strace and got a bunch of output but none of it really makes any sense to me...

Answer (score 0):

If the process is not already running, here are some options I see..

- Is something else listening on 3306? (Unlikely)
- You are running as a user that does not have access to `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock.`  You can try removing this file and restarting the daemon.

Comment: I cannot connect to the MySQL client and there is no process running when I run "ps -ef | grep mysql".

Answer (score 0):

Do you already have another mysqld server running on socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock ?

netstat -l -p -d as root and see if anything is listening on the mysql port.

Comment: I tried the command you gave and there is nothing listening on the port that MySQL is supposed to be running on.

Comment: hmm, bizzare. check your mysqld.conf, and check the running port. Do you have a security policy that stops processes binding to ports?

any thing in /var/log?