# How do I make a program start up automatically on reboot?

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, mysql, web-server, startup-scripts

I am currently renting a VPS that is running CentOS 6.5. I am using it to run a basic forum site, and obviously, I need a web server and MySQL to power that. I have chosen Apache for my web server, and I am using the standard `mysql-server` package for CentOS.

My question is… whenever I reboot my server manually via the `reboot` command, I always have to manually start Apache and MySQL with the following commands:

```
service mysqld start
service httpd start
```

This can be a pain if I happen to forget to start up the individual service. Is there a way I can make it automatically start up whenever I manually reboot my server?

I have done some looking into other questions on ServerFault, and after looking at [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/124292/mysql-server-not-starting-on-boot) and installing `strace`, I ran `strace /etc/init.d/mysqld start` and had a very strange output that didn't make much sense to me. It didn't have any easily decipherable information, but I'm a novice at this type of thing, so I may have not been looking for the right thing.

I have found other pages across the Internet, but they usually seem to be for Debian-based operating systems, and I never seem to be able to use them for what I'm doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The services on a CentOS operating system are managed using `chkconfig`.

Use `chkconfig --list` to review the currently managed services.

You can mark a service to automatically start at a defined runlevel by issuing:

```
# chkconfig someservice on
```

Read the [`chkconfig(8)`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/chkconfig) manpage for the details.

Comment: Awesome, that did for me! `chkconfig httpd on` `chkconfig mysqld on` Thanks for the help.